# Refresh Parent Page Without iframe Returning 'Default" Page

Tags: javascript, iframe, page-refresh

I have an iframe on my index page with a NAME 'mciframe' and ID 'mciframe'.

That iframe will serve as the primary 'content window' for everything viewed on my site.

When my site visitors hit their browser's 'refresh' button of the 'index' page, I would like whatever content they are currently viewing within the iframe at that particular time to refresh, instead of the iframe returning to it's 'default' source page.

I would have posted an example code here, but I did my due diligence and research already, and have already tried about 40 different codes I have gotten from this site today and none of them have worked so far.

Maybe those examples were out of date or not applicable to my particular issue... I don't know.

Hopefully someone have a working suggestion.

Thanks in advance for all suggestions.

Comment: Sorry, not trying to be rude. How do you determine what is shown in the iframe?

Comment: My index page contains my site nav menu, as well as the iframe. All of my site 'content pages' can be called into the iframe through site navigation.

All is working fine. However... if someone is viewing any content page in that iframe, other than the default source page... and they hit their browser 'reload/refresh' button.... the iframe will automatically call up the default source page. I want to prevent that from happening. If they hit their refresh button, I would like the content they are currently viewing in the iframe to remain in the iframe.

Answer (score 1):

## HI!

#### YOU CAN TOTALLY DO THAT!

You can use **localstorage** to save current iframe page!

Here are the **steps** i'd use:

**1.** When user leaves page save current iframe page into local storage.

**2.** When you load page check if there is saved page in your local storage.

**3.** If there is, set `iframe.src` to that value.

**example:**

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("yourIframe");

window.onbeforeunload = saveCurrentPage;
iframe.onload = setPageToBeforeUnload;

function saveCurrentPage(){
localStorage.setItem("lastPageInIframe", iframe.src);
}

function setPageToBeforeUnload(){
iframe.src = localStorage.getItem("lastPageInIframe");
}
```

Please tell me if it worked for you!

Comment: show me some code, I'll try to see what's wrong there

Comment: Tomasz... my iframe is named 'myiframe' (for now), so all I changed in your code was this:

        var iframe = document.getElementById("myiframe");

window.onbeforeunload = saveCurrentPage;
iframe.onload = setPageToBeforeUnload;

function saveCurrentPage(){
localStorage.setItem("lastPageInIframe", iframe.src);
}

function setPageToBeforeUnload(){
iframe.src = localStorage.getItem("lastPageInIframe");
}

And posted it in the head section (with script tags) of the index page. No luck.

Comment: well, try to `console.log` that saved var in localstorage to see if its there, try to see if iframe isn't null, just try to debug a bit

Comment: Other than that... there are no reports on the console log

Answer (score 0):

You can set iframe [src](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_src.asp) attribute from server side and use [onbeforeunload](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onbeforeunload.asp) to send users last url just before refresh;

or you set 'src' from browser side, hold it in [cookie](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) and update whenever you want.

Comment: Thanks Emil. In principal, I understand what you're suggesting. However, I'm not sure how to go about either of those two solutions. Any help would be appreciated.